# How to avoid errors in Vscode for putting header files in a separate directory than src

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Ok so I am having an issue with errors in VSCode. Basically I decided to reorganize and move my header files into a separate folder, "include". My directory put simply is as follows:

```
-build
-include
 |-SDL2
 |-SDL2_Image
 |-someHeaderFile1.h
 |-someHeaderFile2.h
-src
 |-main.cpp
 |-someCppFile.cpp
-Makefile
```

My Makefile contains:

```makefile
SRC_DIR = src
BUILD_DIR = build/debug
CC = g++
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ_NAME = play
INCLUDE_PATHS = -Iinclude -I /include
LIBRARY_PATHS = -Llib
COMPILER_FLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -O0 -g
LINKER_FLAGS = -lsdl2 -lsdl2_image

all:
    $(CC) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(SRC_FILES) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OBJ_NAME)
```

The program compiles and runs, however, my issue is with VSCode as it shows an error having the include as : #include "someHeaderFile1.h" vs #include "../include/someHeaderFile1.h"

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put that folder's path to the `Include path`. One way to do that is shown below. The screenshots are attached with each steps so that it(the process) would be more clear.

##### Step 1

Press `Ctrl + Shift + P`

This will open up a prompt having different options. You have to select the option saying **Edit Configurations**

[image: s1]

##### Step 2

After selecting *Edit Configurations* a page will open with different options. You have to scroll down and go the the option saying **Include Path** and just paste the path to your include folder there.

[image: s2]

Below is the picture after adding the `include` folder's path into the `Include Path` option.

[image: s3]

##### Step 3

Now after adding the path to the include folder into the `Include path` field you can close this window and all the vscode errors that you mentioned will not be there anymore.

Comment: i did try to use this same method for the Qt headers it wont work, do i need to add the exact paht like ```C:/Qt/Qt5_11/..../QtCore``` ?? or where should i add the Qt related paths?

Comment: @lightshadown The one i showed in the above screenshot uses full path like. But you can also use relative path.

Answer (score 1):

If you have install Microsoft C/C++ extension properly, and the directory you show is the root path of your VSCode workspace, you can add `Include path` options in `C/C++: Edit configurations (UI)`, or edit `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` like:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                // Add your custom include path here
                "${workspaceFolder}/include/**",
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            // ...other options
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

For more details refer to the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference).