# OpenCV for C++ in VS Code

Tags: c++, opencv

working with a Jetson Xavier AGX, I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. Recently installed OpenCV via the terminal. It's working with VS code when importing cv2 in Python scripts. But for some reason I cannot make it work with C++.

I'm pretty new to C++ and a bit confused how to import it correctly. I've tried changing "c_cpp_properties.json" to include '/usr/include/opencv4**' but I'm still getting errors when running the code.

**fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory**

Any help appriciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does anyone have any advice on how to avoid errors in Vscode for putting header files in a separate directory than src, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72640804/does-anyone-have-any-advice-on-how-to-avoid-errors-in-vscode-for-putting-header)

Comment: Hey, it seems to me that is the same as configuring the json file, which I've already tried. Only thing I can think of is that I'm including the wrong path.

If I look through my folders, the "opencv.hpp" file is stored in the following location:
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2