# Is there a way to maually include the iostrem and fstream header files In VS code

Tags: c++, iostream, include-path

I am using the C/C++ IntelliSense extesion but using a different compiler for my script.
When I try to include the iostream and fstream header files it tells me to update my include paths and I think that my compiler doesn't have this file in its system include paths and i have not yet found a way to include it manually. I am new to this stuff and it would halp a lot if there is a way.

If i try to use the normal compiler my code wont work and i have not found a way around this problem.
I have also tried to include it manually but could not find a Path to the file.

Comment: *"i have not yet found a way to include it manually"* See [How to avoid errors in Vscode for putting header files in a separate directory than src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72640804/how-to-avoid-errors-in-vscode-for-putting-header-files-in-a-separate-directory-t)