# fatal error: myfunc.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, include, vscode-debugger

os:ubuntu 20.04
vscode version: 1.85.2

I have already set my include path in c_cpp_properties.json file.
However, vscode still cannot find my .h file.

The information of my c_cpp_properties.json is:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/include/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/include"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

The folder tree is:

```
.
├── include
│   └── myfunc.h
├── main.cpp
└── src
    └── myfunc.cpp
```

The error information is:

```
 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

 *  Executing task: C/C++: g++ build active file 

Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/wangc/Documents/work/hello_world/main.cpp -o /home/wangc/Documents/work/hello_world/main
/home/wangc/Documents/work/hello_world/main.cpp:12:10: fatal error: myfunc.h: No such file or directory
   12 | #include "myfunc.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Build finished with error(s).
```

All information is shown in below image.

[bug img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQMbv.png)

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` only affects hints in the editor, not the actual compilation. You need to set the include directory via `-I` GCC flag, in `tasks.json`.

Comment: [How to avoid errors in Vscode for putting header files in a separate directory than src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72640804/how-to-avoid-errors-in-vscode-for-putting-header-files-in-a-separate-directory-t/72640924#72640924)